# React JSX / TSX: import / export multiple modules (theme objects) with Emotion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, emotion

I am using `@emotion/styled` with a separate `theme.jsx` file in a React Typescript project like this:

**theme.jsx**

```
const themeLight = {
  colors: {
    primary: '#141414',
    ...
  }
}
export default themeLight
```

**App.tsx**

```
import themeLight from './theme'
```

This works perfectly as intended, but now I try to add a second theme like this:

**theme.jsx**

```
const themeLight = {...}
const themeDark = {
  colors: {
    primary: '#ffffff',
    ...
  }
}
export { themeLight, themeDark }
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { themeLight, themeDark } from './theme'
```

which results in the error `Module '"./theme.jsx"' has no exported member 'themeLight'`.

Am I missing a simple mistake in my import / export syntax? Is this an issue of cross-importing between jsx / tsx file? Can I change the theme file format to tsx with Emotion?

Comment: the exports/imports look correct to me. does changing it to `.tsx` break or fix anything?

Comment: @axium thank you. I had tried this but forgotten to restart the compiler, duh. After renaming to tsx and [setting up Types](https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#define-a-theme) correctly, it now works. Not sure why the original error came about, but happy to leave it at that!

Answer (score 0):

Renaming `theme.jsx` to `theme.tsx` and [setting up Types](https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#define-a-theme) with an `emotion.d.ts` file solved the problem.